# ColdFusion query.removeRows ignores <cfif> statements and removes all results

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

**This issue is no longer within scope of the title. I am trying to find a way to determine if a PDF being pulled from a db as a Byte Array is read-only, and then remove from the resultset. I have dumped the getinfo on both a read-only and a read/write file and compared the attributes only to find that there is no discernible differences. I have been searching google for other methods, but as of right now I'm stuck.**

I'm trying to filter through a resultset of PDFs and remove any that are password protected. I decrement through an index loop based on the length of the resultset to 1 and compare each PDF(row) with the `IsPDFFile()` function. If the comparison is false then the row should not be deleted. When using the `removeRows` statement the`<cfif>` appears to be ignored and each row is removed indiscriminately.

```
<cfloop index="i" from='#getScans.recordcount#' to='1' step="-1" >
    <cfset pdfDoc = getScans.ATTACHED_DOCUMENT_FILE[i]>
    <cfif NOT IsPDFFile("#pdfDoc#")> <!--- or <cfif NOT IsPDFObject("#pdfDoc#")>  --->
        <cfSet getScans.removeRows(i -1, 1)>
    </cfif>
    <cfoutput> #getScans.recordcount# </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

I am finding very little online that is relevant to my issue. If anyone has some input, that would be wonderful!

**Update:**

I have found that the `IsPDFFile()` is always returning false. It doesn't recognize any of the input as a pdf's. So my problem is not what I had initially thought it was. I keep getting ByteArray errors when trying to handle the PDF's, which are returned from  SQL server.

The error I get when trying to compare the BLOB to anything PDF is: "ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings. - An exception occurred while invoking an event handler method from Application.cfc. The method name is: ..."

...and when I attempt to getinfo using , an error is also thrown: "An error occurred during GETINFO operation in the cfpdf tag.Error: com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.core.cos.CosNull cannot be cast to com.adobe.internal.pdftoolkit.core.cos.CosDictionary The specific sequence of files included or processed is: ..."

I would like to do the following:

perform the code that removes the PDF from the dataset, etc.

This does not work. The getinfo line errors out. Is my syntax perhaps wrong, or perhaps my usage is just inappropriate?

Comment: Are you sure you want to send an alert for every non-PDF you remove back to the browser? That'd get really annoying really quickly. Like... after the first one.

Comment: for sure! The alert is just for debugging. I have found that the IsPDFFile() function is inappropriate here as well. The pdf is coming from a db as ByteArray data, and the comparison always returns false. I am attempting now to use <cfpdf action="getinfo"...  and then compare pdfDoc.encryption, but I'm still getting a ByteArray error.

Comment: Make sure to keep the code in your question up to date with where your troubleshooting has lead you, as well as explaining your progress. It's probably worth googling for "coldfusion storing pdf if db" and reading up in what needs doing to convert the byte array data to/from an actual PDF binary

Comment: Also, while we probably figured out the issue from the *description* of the error ie "..getting a ByteArray error", it is always better to post the *actual* error message itself.

Comment: [Stack Overflow uses a Q&A format](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). So unlike discussion forums, it is typically one question per thread. The points made about the original issues were valid. If you are now facing a different issue, you should open a separate thread. Be sure to explain what you mean by "read only" in this context, given that it is a term normally associated with physical files, not binary data.

Comment: OK, fair enough, I wasn't sure how to handle the thread once the actual issue left the original question. What I mean by read only is that the pdf cannot be written to; when the file was made it was given password protection when writing to the file, but may still be read by anyone.

Comment: Oh .. password protection is a totally different kettle of fish. You should be able to check the pdf properties when the file is added/uploaded. Look under the docs for cfpdf getInfo.  If you run into problems, post back in a separate thread.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking at the first PDF doc in the query each time when you do your `cfset`. You need to reference the current row in the query which is `i`

```
<cfset pdfDoc = getScans.ATTACHED_DOCUMENT_FILE[i]>
```

You can `getInfo` on the PDF and check the encryption field in the struct returned. I'm not sure of all the options returned but an unecrypted PDF returned `No Security` for me.

```
<cfpdf action="getinfo" source="abs/relative path" name="result">
<cfif result.encryption NEQ 'No Security'>
  <cfSet getScans.removeRows(i -1, 1)>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, iterating through the dataset needed to be implemented, you are absolutely correct there. However, this does not solve the Bit array error. I am still unable to check the PDF for encryption.

Comment: @James check the updated answer which I found with a few minutes of googling and creating a test page to check output

Comment: Thank you, that actually seems to let me use the getinfo encryption. The file I am checking is read only, and passes the encryption test, which I assumed it should not. Do you happen to know of a test that will determine weather or not a file is read only?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the comments about the query reference.. That is probably the wrong function in this scenario.  As the name implies, [`IsPDFFile(path)`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/IsPDFFile) expects a file path. Since it sounds like you are passing in the *binary* of a PDF, you want to use [`IsPDFObject(value)`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/IsPDFObject) instead.

> **Value** : A value, typically the PDF object stored as a variable name.
>
> **Returns** : True, if the value returns a valid PDF file. False, otherwise.